# Update Query in Mysql is very slow and need help in writing stored procedures code for getting faster results?

Tags: mysql

Whenever I run an update query from MySQL, it is taking 6 to 7 hours as there are 150 millions of rows in the table and out of it, 36 millions rows are updated.

I don't think it has to take more time for updating with 36 millions rows
Note : `CAT_NO` and `PERIOD_YEAR` are used as partition instead of an index.

```
Update ace_dwh.fa_nls_o set dynamic_l52_weeks_flag = 0 
where cat_no in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) and period_year in (201605,201606); 

Update ace_dwh.fa_nls_o set dynamic_l26_weeks_flag = 0 
where cat_no in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) and period_year in (201611,201512);

Update ace_dwh.fa_nls_o set dynamic_l13_weeks_flag = 0 
where cat_no in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) and period_year in (201702,201703);

Update ace_dwh.fa_nls_o set dynamic_lm1_flag = 0 
where cat_no in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) and period_year in (201704,201705);
```

When I run this update query, it is taking more than 6 hours, which I don't think it should?

My Table looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `fa_nls_o` (        
   `MKT` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,        
   `PROD` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,      
   `PRODUCT_LEVEL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,        
   `CUSTOM_MONTH` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,          
   `CUSTOM_QTR` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,            
   `DYNAMIC_LM1_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,           
   `DYNAMIC_L13_WEEKS_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,             
   `DYNAMIC_L26_WEEKS_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,             
   `DYNAMIC_L52_WEEKS_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,          
   `DYNAMIC_YTD_2016_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,          
   `DYNAMIC_YTD_2017_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,           
   `DYNAMIC_FY_2015_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,             
   `DYNAMIC_FY_2016_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,              
   `DYNAMIC_FY_2014_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,             
   `CURRENT_PERIOD_FLAG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,              
   `CHARACTERESTIC_1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,              
   `CHARACTERESTIC_2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,             
   `CHARACTERESTIC_3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,         
   `CHOOSE_METRIC` double(50,4) DEFAULT NULL,             
   `PERIOD_YEAR` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,             
   `CAT_NO` int(10) DEFAULT NULL             
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8            
 /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (PERIOD_YEAR)              
 SUBPARTITION BY KEY (CAT_NO)             
 SUBPARTITIONS 12          
 (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (201401) ENGINE = InnoDB,       
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (201402) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (201403) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (201404) ENGINE = InnoDB,         
  PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (201405) ENGINE = InnoDB,           
  PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (201406) ENGINE = InnoDB,               
  PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (201407) ENGINE = InnoDB,                
  PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (201408) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (201409) ENGINE = InnoDB,      
  PARTITION p18 VALUES LESS THAN (201410) ENGINE = InnoDB,           
  PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN (201411) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN (201412) ENGINE = InnoDB,               
  PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN (201501) ENGINE = InnoDB,            
  PARTITION p26 VALUES LESS THAN (201502) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p28 VALUES LESS THAN (201503) ENGINE = InnoDB,     
  PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (201504) ENGINE = InnoDB,         
  PARTITION p32 VALUES LESS THAN (201505) ENGINE = InnoDB,       
  PARTITION p34 VALUES LESS THAN (201506) ENGINE = InnoDB,         
  PARTITION p36 VALUES LESS THAN (201507) ENGINE = InnoDB,         
  PARTITION p38 VALUES LESS THAN (201508) ENGINE = InnoDB,      
  PARTITION p40 VALUES LESS THAN (201509) ENGINE = InnoDB,         
  PARTITION p42 VALUES LESS THAN (201510) ENGINE = InnoDB,          
  PARTITION p44 VALUES LESS THAN (201511) ENGINE = InnoDB,            
  PARTITION p46 VALUES LESS THAN (201512) ENGINE = InnoDB,           
  PARTITION p48 VALUES LESS THAN (201601) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p50 VALUES LESS THAN (201602) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p52 VALUES LESS THAN (201603) ENGINE = InnoDB,            
  PARTITION p54 VALUES LESS THAN (201604) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p56 VALUES LESS THAN (201605) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p58 VALUES LESS THAN (201606) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p60 VALUES LESS THAN (201607) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p62 VALUES LESS THAN (201608) ENGINE = InnoDB,               
  PARTITION p64 VALUES LESS THAN (201609) ENGINE = InnoDB,          
  PARTITION p66 VALUES LESS THAN (201610) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p68 VALUES LESS THAN (201611) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p70 VALUES LESS THAN (201612) ENGINE = InnoDB,                 
  PARTITION p72 VALUES LESS THAN (201701) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p74 VALUES LESS THAN (201702) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p76 VALUES LESS THAN (201703) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p78 VALUES LESS THAN (201704) ENGINE = InnoDB,               
  PARTITION p80 VALUES LESS THAN (201705) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p82 VALUES LESS THAN (201706) ENGINE = InnoDB,               
  PARTITION p84 VALUES LESS THAN (201707) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p86 VALUES LESS THAN (201708) ENGINE = InnoDB,              
  PARTITION p88 VALUES LESS THAN (201709) ENGINE = InnoDB,            
  PARTITION p90 VALUES LESS THAN (201710) ENGINE = InnoDB,               
  PARTITION p92 VALUES LESS THAN (201711) ENGINE = InnoDB,             
  PARTITION p94 VALUES LESS THAN (201712) ENGINE = InnoDB,               
  PARTITION p96 VALUES LESS THAN (201801) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

I Heard that if we create a stored procedure instead of update query, then the query results will be faster.

Can you help me how to write this stored procedures based on these 4 update queries instead of direct update queries?

I tried Stored procedures like this :

```
DELIMITER $$     
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `proc_WeekFlagUpdate`()    
BEGIN    

UPDATE ace_dwh.fa_nls_o     
   SET dynamic_l52_weeks_flag = 0
 WHERE cat_no IN (0 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
   AND period_year IN (201605 , 201606);

UPDATE ace_dwh.fa_nls_o 
   SET dynamic_l26_weeks_flag = 0
 WHERE cat_no IN (0 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
   AND period_year IN (201611 , 201512);

UPDATE ace_dwh.fa_nls_o 
   SET dynamic_l13_weeks_flag = 0
 WHERE cat_no IN (0 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
   AND period_year IN (201702 , 201703);

UPDATE ace_dwh.fa_nls_o 
   SET dynamic_lm1_flag = 0
 WHERE cat_no IN (0 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
   AND period_year IN (201704 , 201705);

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It takes still more time? Need help ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored routines can't help with non-indexed tables.

Without indexes rows are searched by brute force. Create the complex index for (cat_no, period_year):

```
CREATE TABLE `fa_nls_o` (        
   . . . . .
   `CAT_NO` int(10) DEFAULT NULL             
    INDEX `cat_no_period_year` (cat_no, period_year)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I can't add index instead of procedures, as mysql process is connected to Talend application where somewhere mass truncation process go through for partition. If we use index,then we have to go for deletion process,it will take more time for deletion in place of truncation

Comment: My condolescences. You can't do anything. Stored routines are not an option.

Comment: we tried indexing before partitioning : STart Transaction;  Update ace_dwh.fa_nls_o set dynamic_l52_weeks_flag = 0 
where cat_no in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) and period_year in (201605,201606); commit ;. Note : we added  indexing to both cat_no,period_year before, still it took more than hour.That is why we switched to partition

Comment: Partitioning do not replace the indexes. Partitioning allows to split indexes into the smaller and faster pieces.

Comment: we tried stored procedures but tat took me more time, If i run through update process,it took me little time than stored procedures. why is it opposite

Comment: There is no difference how SQL statements are invoked. You can run them directly or you can wrap them into the routine, execution time will be exactly the same. Parsing, preparation and opimization overhead for direct queries is completely unsignificant for heavy queries that took more than few milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATEing` 36 million rows takes a long time.  Period.

The rows need to be copied in case of power failure and automatic ROLLBACK.  This is costly for 36M rows.  Period.

Some things can mitigate the problem.

- Smaller is faster -- shrink the datatypes.  If the FLAGs are 0/1, use a 1-byte TINYINT instead of a 4-byte INT.  Etc.
- Indexes are better than Partitioning.
- More than 50 partitions (including subpartitions) is inefficient.
- How many `cat_no` values are there?  If only 12, then filtering or partitioning on that column does nothing (other than confuse the reader).
- Don't include future partitions (other than `LESS THAN MAXVALUE`); it slows things down.
- Update in chunks.  [*Discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks)

But, most importantly, it is bad design to need to modify millions of rows on a regular basis.  Rethink the application with the intent of avoiding such.  Perhaps... Have a table with 3 columns: period_year, cat_no, flag.  That would have only a few hundred rows, not millions.  And it would be extremely fast to change the *one* row instead of the millions.  You could `JOIN` to the table when you need the value.  (Be sure to have it indexed -- `PRIMARY KEY(period_year, cat_no)`!!)

Comment: The reason we cant add Primary key to Period_year and cat_no because it has many duplicate values,it is kind of stock items application. we tried adding Index on both period year and cat_no but didn't helped out ,it takes same time as with partitioning. The reason we added partitioning bcoz there is process of  truncation goes on ETL depend upon cat_no and periodyear.

Comment: Might help:  Partition `BY RANGE(one of them)` and start `PRIMARY KEY` with the other one.

Comment: Primary key to cat_no not possible since there will be many duplicate of 0, 1 etc till 12. This is TABLEU application requirement. Thinking of JOIN query but that too hampers the performance. Can you suggest more?

Comment: No, _start of_ the PK -- That is, add some column(s) _after_ it to make a unique "composite" key.  Doing this "clusters" all the rows with the desired cat_no together.  However, are there only 12 cat_no values?  and You always ask for all of them?  Are the rows somewhat evenly distributed between the values?

Comment: @RickJames *"..are there only 12 cat_no values? and You always ask for all of them?.."* Look like extremely bad overall design to me.